# Can you interrupt BufferedReader.readLine() with Future.cancel(true)?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

Let's say I started a thread and I have something like this:

```
 ...//initiate all the socket connection
 future = executor.submit
 (  new Runnable()
    {   public void run()
        {   ...
            ...      
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
            {  //do something here

            }

    }

 );
```

executor is a ExecutorService object and in is a BufferedReader object

I know you can close the socket from a different thread to interrupt this thread. But when I try to use future.cancel(true) method, even though it returns true, the thread seems still running, anybody know why?  or in.readLine() cannot be interrrupted this way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can you interrupt BufferedReader.readLine() with Future.cancel(true)?

All `future.cancel(true)` does is to call `thread.interrupt()` on the associated thread.  This will cause `sleep()` and `wait()` operations to throw an `InterruptedException` and will interrupt some special [NIO channels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html).

But chances are your `BufferedReader` will not be interrupted since it is most likely reading from a "normal" socket or file.  As you mention, closing the underlying socket from a different thread is the best way to kill such an IO method.

Answer (score 3):

You can close the in stream to trigger an IOException.  Otherwise a readLine() can block forever.

I have looked at using JavaLangAccess.blockedOn() but it looks rather low level.

Answer (score 1):

`readLine` does not throw `InterruptedException` so it will not be affected if the thread it runs in is interrupted. You need to explicitly check the interrupted status of the thread:

```
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                //You can deal with the interruption here
            }
        }
```

But if it blocks while executing `readLine` , the only way to interrupt it is to close the underlying stream which will throw an IOException.