# Check for interrupt in zero loop thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I need to time limit a long running function which has zero loops. I run that function using a `Callable` and call `get` on the future with a timeout value. AFAIU, `future.cancel(true)` will set the interrupt flag for the function thread. But until and unless I check and handle Thread.isInterrupted() in `longRunningFunction()` my code will be unaware that it has to exit and even after `shutdownNow()` the function will not terminate.

- How to check for interrupted in `longRunningFunction()`? The check needs to be prompt i.e if the check is put at specific points then until those points are hit, the thread will not handle the interrupt.
- Is there any other graceful way to time limit function?
- Why can't I just kill all threads in executor pool? As per [JavaDocs for ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()) the pool will never terminate until the threads handle interrupt and terminate themselves.

```
public class Test {

  public void longRunningFunction() {
    /*
   Long running code without loop
     */
  }

  public Void call() {
    try {
      longRunningFunction()
    } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
      logger.error("{} Error : {}", TAG, exception.getStackTrace().join("\n"))
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      logger.error("[call]{} Error : {}", TAG, exception.getStackTrace().join("\n"))
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    Future<Void> future = executor.submit(new Test())
    int timeoutSeconds = 5
    println "Setting timeout to " + timeoutSeconds
    try {
      future.get(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS) 
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
      future.cancel(true)
      logger.error("Could not finish processing within {} seconds", timeoutSeconds)
    } finally {
      executor.shutdownNow()
      executor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      logger.error("Shutting down")
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit**
The question linked for marking duplicate suggests that shared variables are the way to go, which is a known fact as mentioned in the question. The question is to how seamlessly check for that boolean flag i.e `Thread.isInterrupted`.

Comment: Even if the `longRunningFunction` has no loops is not plausible that there are no intermediate steps inside this function where check for the interrupt flag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you kill a thread in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java)

Comment: The mentioned link suggests that shared variables (the `isInterrupted` flag here) are the way to go. That is a known fact. The question is how to seamlessly check for that boolean variable.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't see much alternatives than put into your code few checks for the `isInterrupted` flag.

Comment: That is a way, but I find that hackish and I want to avoid hacks in a multithreaded code as far as possible (There are multiple various other calls in the method which might run for a long time depending on input)

Comment: Ok, I got your idea. So, let's say, what's is the expected behaviour if one of the other long calls is running for long long time?

Comment: You say, "no loops."  I presume that means no loops _and no recursion_ (i.e., no  single place where you can put a statement that will be executed many times during the long run.)  And, I presume that it does not call any blocking function, because a blocking function would throw `InterruptedException.`  So what's left?  How long can a function call take if it has no loops, no recursion, and does not call any blocking functions?

Comment: @jameslarge I am downloading a page using BufferedReader.readLine() which [apparently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979485/can-you-interrupt-bufferedreader-readline-with-future-canceltrue) does not throw InterruptedException

Comment: @freedev If one of the other long calls is running for long long time I want to throw exception and return control, so that the parent thread can terminate.

Comment: OK, I am officially disqualified from giving out any more Java advice.  Looks like there is no way to get an `InterruptedException` when reading from any kind of `InputStream`.  Sounds like your `InputStream` was obtained from a `Socket`.  What happens if one thread closes the socket while another thread is waiting to receive bytes?

Comment: If a single call to `BufferedReader.readLine()` takes a significant amount of time, you should probably manage the buffering yourself so you can check for interruptions at reasonable intervals.

Comment: @jameslarge Yes. The `InputStream` is obtained from `HttpUrlConnection`. The socket is not shared among threads. Are you suggesting closing the socket from another thread which will throw an `IOException` where I can do the processing I want to do for `InterruptedException`?

Answer (score 1):

The only way beyond checking the `isInterrupted` flag is to kill the thread, control the current state and reconcile it somehow. You can obviously encapsulate this inside a class that makes it appear as the `isInterrupted` flag has been checked.